# Error creating component in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0

i was doing a web app and it was doing fine until i backup my project and formatted ma PC, re install visual studio 2012. now when i switch to  source code it works fine but when i switch design view i get a bunch of error on the place holders.

```
Error creating control - (Content)
cannot find type system.componentmodel.toolboxitemfilterattribute in module system.dll
```

but the app works fine when running , i just cant edit in designer view
[image: Image error message]

Comment: It looks like your VS.NET install is probably corrupt. I'd try reinstalling.

Comment: last time i installed it took 2hours on ma old pc

Comment: Well, then I guess it must be installed correctly, then.

Comment: i created a new project and it didnt display any, error so it must be from the project am opening maybe compatibility because originally i made the project on visual studio 2012 on TFS and now am working on VS2012 update 1 with no TFS (i disconnected it from the team foundation server);

Comment: Note Guys here that system.componentm .. is not actual system file it is myprojects namespace. (i.e system.dll) is the compiled output of the system project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found out [a similar error](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/general-discussions/error-creating-control-solution-found.aspx) and the solution there works great.

All I had to do was delete all files in the bin directory of my project and reopen the project.. lol